# HttpClient Result conversion time out

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am developing a small Xamarin forms application that works with a asp.net web API (that I created).

What I want to achieve is to check if the API is online/running or not(Just some error handling). What I've done is added a test controller to the API that when requested returns a true. If the API is online I get true and it works, when it's offline and I try to convert the result to a bool it takes a very long time (+20 seconds) before going into catch block, and in this time my application is hanging.

Please Advise what to do or if there is a better way in handling this as I am new to both (Xamarin forms & API's)

```
public static bool testConnection()
{
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var content = _client.GetStringAsync(apiUrl + "/api/Test");//url Path
        bool ConnectionStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(content.Result);//This line takes very long before jumping to catch block
        if (ConnectionStatus)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this you *actual* code? The method signature is void instead of bool...

Comment: @Cal279 yes sorry typed from memory but its exact code now

Comment: _client.GetStringAsync returns a Task. So either do a `await` or `.ContinueWith()`

Comment: you need to set the Timeout value to a lower number if you want it to return sooner

Comment: @Jason thanks for the hint but how do i do that?

Comment: there should be a Timeout property on HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx

`HttpClient` has a `Timeout` property, which defaults to 100 seconds. Lowering this value will cause the request to timeout and throw an exception sooner.

```
_client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```